# Which interest rate to use for computing IV: FlatForward doesn't make sense?

Tags: quantlib, volatility

I am confused by `quantlib` `yield` classes: it doesn't make sense to use one `interest rate`, e.g., today's rate, for an `option chain` that has different `expiry`.

Say you have a `yield curve` at time `t` (today) that goes out from one month to thirty years. If you have several `European` `equity` `options` that `expires` in say several possibilities (an option chain): a week, three weeks, one month, three months or six months, to compute the `implied volatility`, do you still use for each `expiry`, the `interest rate` (`QuantLib::Rate riskFreeRate`) ;closest to today, or do you use the `yield curve` and instead of using `FlatForward` use something else?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that sort of what I was asking for [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32239/which-risk-free-interest-rate-to-use-in-black-scholes-equation) I am still uncertain, but this seems like a logical answer.

So if I have a `European option` and it `expires` in six months, one possibility is to use the six month `t-bill` [or corresponding rate on the YC] `rate` and annualize it using `FlatForward`.